# Get the InstanceKey of the receiver from a method on a CallString in WALA?

Tags: java, static-analysis

I have a `com.ibm.wala.ipa.callgraph.propagation.cfa.CallString` that I obtain via the following sequence of calls:

- com.ibm.wala.ipa.callgraph.propagation.AbstractTypeInNode.getNode()
- com.ibm.wala.ipa.callgraph.CGNode.getContext()
- com.ibm.wala.ipa.callgraph.propagation.cfa.CallStringContext.get(ContextKey)

From the `CallString`, I can get at arrays of `com.ibm.wala.classLoader.CallSiteReference`s and `com.ibm.wala.classLoader.IMethod`s, respectively. For (potentially) each of the calls in the string, I would like to know the `com.ibm.wala.ipa.callgraph.propagation.InstanceKey` of the *receiver* of the call. What is the best way to go about this?

One (perhaps primitive) way I can see about going about this is that I can retrieve the "programmer counter" number from the `CallString`. For example, for the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  Stream o1=new ArrayList<>().stream();
  BaseStream o2=o1.unordered();
}
```

This is the node corresponding to the allocation of the object created as a result of the call to `unordered()`:

```
Node: < Primordial, Ljava/util/stream/ReferencePipeline, unordered()Ljava/util/stream/Stream; >
```

And the `Context` extracted from the node, which was generated using a nCFA where n = 2:

```
CallStringContext: [ java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.unordered()Ljava/util/stream/BaseStream;@1 p.B.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V@12 ]
```

12 seems to be the program counter in the `main()` method where `unordered()` is called. Here's the SSA form for the same code:

```
Instructions:
BB0
BB1
0   v3 = new <Application,Ljava/util/ArrayList>@0(line 10)
BB2
2   invokespecial < Application, Ljava/util/ArrayList, <init>()V > v3 @4 exception:v4(line 10)
BB3
3   v6 = invokevirtual < Application, Ljava/util/ArrayList, stream()Ljava/util/stream/Stream; > v3 @7 exception:v5(line 10)
BB4
6   v8 = invokeinterface < Application, Ljava/util/stream/Stream, unordered()Ljava/util/stream/BaseStream; > v6 @12 exception:v7(line 11) {6=[o1]}
...
```

From this, we can see that the instruction at program counter 12 is indeed a call to `unordered()`. We can also see that the receiver is `v6`. So, at least here we know, by using a combination of the SSA and the call graph, the IR variable representing the instance receiver. The question remains, however, is it possible to get the `InstanceKey` of the receiver object this way?